# Can not pass a string as function argument Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, function

I'm beginning with JQuery. When I want to pass a String as argument in a function, sometimes it won't work and I do not know why...

This is an example:

```
$(document).ready(test());

function test() {
    $('path[secteur]').each(function () {
        if ($(this).attr('id') == ("23C01")) {
            id = ($(this).attr('id'));
            afficher(id);

        }
    })
}

function afficher(mo) {
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "<p id=" + mot + " onclick='tester(" + mot + ")'>  step 1</p>";

}

function tester(verbe) {
    document.getElementById(verbe).innerHTML = "step 2";
}
```

On this example it's works just fine for "afficher" but it does not work with "tester". When I try to click on the generated HTML, I get an error : "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list"

Anyone knowing why?

Comment: Remove braces `()` from `$(document).ready(test());`. Use `$(document).ready(test);`

Comment: Your declaration for `afficher()` calls the parameter `mo`, but the code calls it `mot`.

Comment: There seem to be a number of things wrong with this code.  You never define the variable `mot` for example.  You're also executing `test()` *before* the `document`'s ready event (see @Tushar's comment), so when you invoke `afficher(id)` that `id` value may not have anything in it.  As for the error itself, what's the exact line of code which produces it?  You're dynamically adding HTML with embedded JavaScript.  If that embedded JavaScript is malformed, *look at it* and see why it might be malformed.

Comment: What @Pointy said, that and you probably need to add quotes to the parameter being passed as string (may be escape a quote before and after ` + mo + `.

Comment: NB: `$(this).attr('id') === this.id`, but the latter requires no function calls, instead of the two visible ones and several more made in the background by jQuery for the former.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Js side: you have lost qoutes for string in function call.
2. Html side: you don't have escaping of attribute value.
3. All your functions need to be global.
4. `$(document).ready(test());` - `test` is executed immediatly.

And the whole code is awful.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference if you call a function in the program context:

```
var test = 2;
test++;
test = domymath( test );
alert( test );
```

Or if you call you function with callback of a function:

```
var test = 2;
test++;
test = domymath( test, alert );
```

You can pass arguments/ values in `()` to a function if you call it in the program context, but you can't pass them if you call a function as a callback.
Because the for the callback you only define the name of the function which should be called.

So in your case use:

```
$(document).ready( test );
// calls test();

$(document).ready( function () {
      test( one, two );
});
// calls test( one, two );
```